# Apply a function over last two dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

How can I apply a function over last two dimensions? E.g. I generated an array below of (2,3,3) dimensions, the resulting array should have the same dimenstions where the function is apply to a[0,:,:] and a[1,:,:]. I understand I can go with a `for` loop, but might there be an in-built function specially for these type of operations?

```
a = np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3)
c = []
for i in range(2):
    c.append(np.linalg.pinv(a[i,:,:]))
result = np.array(c)
```

Here I used `np.linalg.pinv` but assume a generic function `f: (n,k)-> (n,k)`, e.g `f = lambda x: x**3 +61`

Comment: Your generic function has to be run once for each 2d subarray, right?  `numpy` doesn't have a tool to compile your function and run it in a compiled loop.  Your append loop is essentially the same as a list comprehension, `np.array([pinv(a1) for a1 in a])`.  In general, (relatively) few iterations on a complex task is not suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a 3D array, you can directly [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) your function on the array, this will loop over the first dimension and apply the function on the remaining dimensions:

```
out = np.array(list(map(np.linalg.pinv, a)))
```

*NB. this is **not** vectorized.*

Output:

```
array([[[-5.55555556e-01, -1.66666667e-01,  2.22222222e-01],
        [-5.55555556e-02,  1.98795266e-16,  5.55555556e-02],
        [ 4.44444444e-01,  1.66666667e-01, -1.11111111e-01]],

       [[-1.30555556e+00, -1.66666667e-01,  9.72222222e-01],
        [-5.55555556e-02,  1.31569730e-15,  5.55555556e-02],
        [ 1.19444444e+00,  1.66666667e-01, -8.61111111e-01]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
a = np.arange(18).reshape(2, 3, 3)

a = np.linalg.pinv(a[np.arange(2), :, :])
print(a)
```

Prints:

```
[[[-5.55555556e-01 -1.66666667e-01  2.22222222e-01]
  [-5.55555556e-02  1.98795266e-16  5.55555556e-02]
  [ 4.44444444e-01  1.66666667e-01 -1.11111111e-01]]

 [[-1.30555556e+00 -1.66666667e-01  9.72222222e-01]
  [-5.55555556e-02  1.31569730e-15  5.55555556e-02]
  [ 1.19444444e+00  1.66666667e-01 -8.61111111e-01]]]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right for this particular case as `np.linalg.pinv` operates on the last two dimensions anyways, so `np.linalg.pinv(a)` works. But for about the generic `func` that outputs same dimensions as input: (3,3) -> (3,3)?

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 Can you make an concrete example of such function?

Comment: added. I was thinking about a function like `np.apply_over_axes` but I apparently misunderstood it.

Comment: Re `apply_over_axes`, take its example seriously.  `np.sum` is a function that takes an `axis` parameter.  So to add over 2 dimensions, you have to apply it first to one, and then to the other.  Now `np.sum` takes a tuple, so this `over` is not needed (and probably was never that useful).  But the function you propose doesn't take an `axis` parameter.  More often people try to use `apply_along_axis`, but worry that it only passes 1d arrays.  But even when it works it isn't a speed tool.